# JMX: Converting AttributeList to Map

Tags: java, jmx

I'm coding a monitoring app that utilizes JMX. I'd like to convert the `AttributeList` returned into a `Map` whose keys are the attribute names and values the attribute values. In my search, I've only found a way that depends on the use of an EJB container. What I want is a light-weight solution that does not depend on any container. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I have understood your question correctly, but this method will convert an [AttributeList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/management/AttributeList.html) to a map.

```
public Map<String, Object> attrListToMap(AttributeList attrList) {
    Map<String, Object> attributeMap = new HashMap<String, Object>(attrList.size());
    for(Attribute attr: attrList.asList()) {
        attributeMap.put(attr.getName(), attr.getValue());
    }
    return attributeMap;
}
```